# How to enable php in NixOs

Tags: nixos, nix

I'm trying to setup an LAMP environment with NixOs.
I managed to have mysql and apache running, but I can't find a way 
to enable php. 
At the moment, apache is *serving* php file as text instead of executing it.

I've seen there is a `enablePHP` option in the `appache-httpd/default.nix` file but it doesn't seem visible (it doesn't appear when I do `man configuration.nix` and I get an error message if I try to set it to true).

Comment: I suggest to ask this question in freenode #nixos irc channel

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the version of nixpkgs used to build your system (and the `configuration.nix` man page) is older than the version of [nixpkgs](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs) you are looking at. After an update of your system the option should be documented in the `configuration.nix` man page and work as expected.

I successfully [use](https://github.com/chaoflow/nixos-configurations/blob/master/configuration-eve.nix#L288) `enablePHP` and `enableUserDir` to render php files in my user's public_html. An `.htaccess` file with `DirectoryIndex index.php` further enables php index files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also in the process of setting up a php stack (using nginx / php-fpm) and I found the following, which might answer your question.
Use the `extraModules` parameter of the httpd config to enable the php module, like so:

```
  extraModules = [
    { name = "php5"; path = "${pkgs.php}/modules/libphp5.so"; }
  ];
```

I found this example here: https://github.com/svanderburg/disnix-stafftracker-php-example/blob/master/deployment/configurations/test-vm1-httpd.nix